# HTACCESS issue- domain vs subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I have got lots of ideas from google and stackoverflow- but none of those was exactly what i am looking for. here is scenario-

1. I have bought a hosting space from a provider. I had to provide a domain name(let abc.com) as the primary domain of that hosting space.
2. Then i have found that i have to put all the contents for that rimary domain(abc.com) into the document root directly. that is no directory like www/abc or www/abc.com.
3. Then I googled and found lots of .htaccess solution. I picked the following one-

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc.com/(.*) [NC]

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc.com/$1
4. I have just paste above lines at the end of the existing .htaccess file (default).
   It was working fine. I have been using www/abc.com directory for my abc.com domain from then.
5. Recently I have added some subdomains (let xyz.abc.com) to my abc.com domain. But it is behaving strange with me. all subdomains are looking for its contents from abc.com/subdomain (eg. abc.com/xyz.abc.com)
6. This time i am getting no solution over google (i may missed it).

Someone help me please- i am in bad shape.

**EDITED:**
Following lines were in WebRoot .htaccess from the beginning. After that I have added additional lines as mentioned above(3,4)

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName abc.com
AuthUserFile /home/abc/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/abc/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp\
```

**EDITED AGAIN:**
There are some other domains(except the main domain abc.com) in the same hosting space. Those domains have some working sub-domains. But sub-domain of main domain is not working as i explained above.

Comment: How did you add the subdomains in the webserver configuration? Also, has the `.htacces` been modified after you added the subd's?

Comment: @methode: when i add a subdoamin no changes comes into .htaccess

Comment: Okay. Do the subdomains work? I.e. if you go to xyz.abc.com, do you get the expected page?
I'm asking this because certain webservers (i.e. those that are managed w/ cPanel) are configured to serve subdomains from subdirectories of the web-root, just like you described.
Considering that in your absolute path you have /home/abc/public_html/ , your server is managed with cPanel/WHM and thus the 'issue' you have is actually the expected behavior.
I believe your best bet would be to either disallow completely the access to abc.com/xyz/abc.com or just 301 redirect it to the subdomain.

Comment: as i have explained- xyz.abc.com goes to abc.com/xyz.abc.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$
```

Now the rules do not match your subdomains anymore.

**Update**

```
# catch www.abc.com and abc.com (and wwwwwwwwwww.abc.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(w+\.)?abc\.com$
```

Comment: thanks a lot @toscho. I will check it tonight and let you know.

Comment: it works fine except www.abc.com. when i goes to www.abc.com it shows the folder content (since there is no index file).

Comment: I have added a better RewriteCondition to match the www prefix.